# Light and GFCI off 240v well circuit transformer

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v, transformer

Due to costs of pulling I decided to try a used transformer as of infrequent usage of the GFCI and more of lighting. I opened the mobile home's 200 amp breaker box at the pole. It has a double breaker for both hot legs, 90 amp double breaker for the heat pump package unit. It also has the 20 amp pump double breaker.

The pump uses 12-2 cable with ground. I added a 20 amp double breaker with 12-3 with a ground uf cable in conduit out to two sheds. One 110v leg to one shed and the other to the shed beside it. There was no neutral white wires except the one from the new uf cable.

The neutral from the pole is bonded to the bus bars on either side. My white neutral to the sheds is the only one there. There in no ground rod for the box but the ground wire is going into the meter box. The connector between the meter and the breaker box is pvc so I'm not sure if the neutral is electrically bonded to the power pole neutral to the meter case.

As for the double wide there must be a ground/ground rod for the 200 amp interior breaker box. As for the transformer I found these two on ebay:  [one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Jefferson-Powerformer-211-061-Transformer-75-KVA-240-480V-120-240V/274024895186?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m1438.l2649), [two](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Schneider-1-5S1F-Square-D-Dry-Type-Transformer-240-x-480V-Primary-/392572147274?_trksid=p2047675.l2557&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&nma=true&si=f7ACH99UHAlZUAOqhnL6QLRQ7Qw%253D&orig_cvip=true&nordt=true&rt=nc)

Thanks for all that. Looks like it might be less hassle/expense to just put the gfi at the front corner of the house which is about 30 ft from the pump house. Yes is is a structure that I can stand up in as I wanted to store some yard tools in it. I guess it is easier to just add a light. Here is what's out there. First there is a waterproof box with the 12-2 with ground from the breaker box, and 12-2 with the ground going to the pressure switch.They are seperated by a double pole switch to disconnect the pump to work on it. The bare ground wire is attached to the metal box ground lug and a ground lug in the pressure switch with the ground coming up from the pump. I added a waterproof box for the switch above (rather than smash it all in tha single box) and the gfi. That box has a tap in the rear to receive the x-former out for the gfi/light. The boxes are connected by a metal nipple but no actual green wire from ground lugs in each box. Out the top of that box using the "load" connections goes a green, white and black through conduit to an octagon box at the ceiling with a porcelin lamp holder that has an outlet and pull switch. I replaced the old douple pole switch with a new 30 amp one. Ok, so switching to just a light in there I have an extra porcelin single lamp holder for two bulbs in series. I can easily change things around as I have extra electrical parts. If I can get a 220 v lamp with a regular base, do I use the bare wire connected to that green ground going the the light for ID purposes or the white ?

Comment: What is the question? Please revise to make it more clear. Also, if you're referring to some other question you need to link that here. Don't expect visitors to know where it might be. Every question needs to stand on its own.

Comment: Looking for transformer recommendations and comments on my electrical service.

Comment: Yes, I am very unclear on what you are doing.  You seem to be skipping a lot of description.  You talk about the main panel, say you are running 12/3 but said you don't want to pull cable because of **cost** (pulling wires through conduit is free). Very very confused.  .

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to confuse you. Harper you seemed well versed in your comments. I explained the breaker box set up for your comments. Seems the box had only 220/240 circuits as no other neutral wires. Seems the transformer idea would be less expensive for a used transformer vrs buying 4 seperate thhn wires. Thought you could look at the two transformers.

Comment: The second one, the 1.5 kva, would give 1500 watts.  However buying these on eBay is nuts.  You'll pay more for shipping than for the transformer.   I would get them locally, e.g. off Craigslist.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looks like I'll spend like $80+ for the wire/supplies if I would do a re-pull. As for a transformer the local area CL doesn't have what I need. I stopped driving years ago so get may Items shipped in. The .75 kva (750 watts?) be good for a light and occasional weedwacker/drill ect. It is $44. Do you see any others on ebay would work ? As for the breaker box, I never worked on one that didn't have a gound. The ground goes in the meter box. Is the neutral in the meter bonded to the case. Seems some electrical practices vary from my old homestead in Pa.

Comment: Can you please add some more context to your question? I'm kinda lost as to what you're trying to accomplish here...

Comment: Looking for thoughts on my breaker box setup and transformer to convert my 240v pump circuit for a light and gfi socket.

Comment: install a 240V light, and use battery tools.

Comment: @K S - I suggest you make a separate question to ask about your service and grounding to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to the part about whether to use a transformer or run a new circuit to your newly built pump house - not the questions about your service / bonding / grounding.

The Schneider 1.5SF1 you found used for $30 is a good deal, a suitable 1.5KVA transformer seems to go for around $200 new.  However that is a little shy of what you need to run a 15A circular saw, which is 1800VA.  It might be OK but I would go with a 2KV transformer myself.

I don't think you can just tap that pump circuit to supply the transformer.  I think you'd have to install a 240V subpanel and put separate breakers for the pump and transformer.  The subpanel won't necessarily require a main breaker but if no main you'll need a disconnect.  It will require a ground rod.  If you screw up the grounding / bonding it could be unsafe.

For all that trouble, I'd be putting in a GFCI breaker for $50 and running another circuit out to that pump house.  Another way to go to shave off a few bucks, use a $10 regular breaker and feed through a $20 GFCI receptacle at the panel (plus a few bucks for the box, bubble cover etc. if you don't have on hand).  Plus you get another receptacle that way.

Wire - You'd need two wires for the pump, two for the receptacle, and one for the ground wire.  So for a 75' run, your best deal might be a 350' 12/3 coilpack for $125 or so.  It's a few bucks more than 500' black, 100' white, and 100' green at about $115, but you get a lot more for your money.  The 100' rolls are a ripoff.

There is a rule that you can't run two circuits to an outbuilding, if you run more than one you have to set a subpanel.  I don't think a shelter built like a box around your pump would count as a separate building.  If it's more of a shed you can stand up inside, it is.  If that's the case, I'd probably just put that convenience receptacle on the outside on a post.